# Trigger not working with correct if statment

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Ok this is probably an easy fix, but i can't seem to find the problem.
i have a table defined like this :

```
CREATE TABLE Prenotazione (
Mat_docente         char(10),
Nome_sede           varchar2(30),
Num_aula            varchar2(3),
Tipo_aula           varchar2(15),
Motivazione         varchar2(20)    NOT NULL,
Affluenza           NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
Data_ptz_aula       date            NOT NULL,
Inizio_ptz_aula     date,
Fine_ptz_aula       date,
--
CONSTRAINT fk_Prenotazione_docente  FOREIGN KEY (Mat_docente) REFERENCES Docente(Mat_docente) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT fk_Prenotazione_aula     FOREIGN KEY (Nome_sede,Num_aula,Tipo_aula) REFERENCES Aula(Nome_sede,Num_aula,Tipo_aula) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT pk_Prenotazione          PRIMARY KEY (Mat_docente,Inizio_ptz_aula,Fine_ptz_aula),
CHECK       (trunc(inizio_ptz_aula) = trunc(fine_ptz_aula)), -- data inizio = data fine // prenotazione giornaliera
CHECK       ( Inizio_ptz_aula < Fine_ptz_aula ),                -- ora inizio < ora fine   // coerenza temporale
CHECK       (Motivazione in ('Lezione','Seminario','Esercitaz','Esame','Assemblea','Altro'))
```

at wich i assign a trigger, specifically this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Controllo_prenotazione
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Prenotazione
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
EX_ONE EXCEPTION;
EX_TWO EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
IF trunc(:NEW.Inizio_ptz_aula) < trunc(next_day(sysdate,1))
THEN RAISE EX_ONE;
END IF;
IF to_number(to_char(sysdate,'d'),'9') > 5
THEN RAISE EX_TWO;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN EX_ONE THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-200011,'Non è possibile prenotare nella settimana corrente');
WHEN EX_TWO THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-200012,'Non è possibile prenotare nel weekend');
END;
/
```

Now, when i try to insert a row, let's say :

```
    insert into prenotazione values ('1124000003',
'Centro Direzionale',
NULL,
'Aula',
'Lezione',
250,
sysdate,
to_date('28-03-2015 16:30','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'), 
to_date('28-03-2015 18:30','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'));
```

I get this error :

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week
ORA-06512: at "ADMIN.CONTROLLO_PRENOTAZIONE", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ADMIN.CONTROLLO_PRENOTAZIONE'
```

referred to the first IF clause.
What's happening ?
The parameter

```
trunc(next_day(sysdate,1))
```

works as intended, as i can say after checking on dual table and the insert works without the trigger, so it's not a ddl related problem.

Thank you for your time and for any help provided in advance.

Comment: Do you happen to have any other triggers on that table that might be running with bad/old code?

Comment: The second parameter of `next_day` is a string: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions093.htm

Comment: it works even with numbers

Comment: If you read the doc that @Laurence points you to, you will find `The argument char must be a day of the week in the date language of your session, either the full name or the abbreviation.` If you want tomorrow you need only do `TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1`.

Comment: NUMBER implicitly converts to VARCHAR2. Aside from that... @darkpirate - Try adding `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_char(trunc(:NEW.Inizio_ptz_aula), 'dd-mm-yyyy') ||  ' < ' || to_char(trunc(next_day(sysdate,1)), 'dd-mm-yyyy'));` just before your IF statement and see what is printed in your output when you run.

Comment: i want the next monday to be considered

Comment: @darkpirate, `NEXT_DAY()` works with a number in SQL, but may not in PL/SQL. Try using `Sunday` instead of `1` (or `Monday` if your week starts on Monday).

Comment: @gmiley strangely it doesn't print nothing, even with serveroutput on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that `NEXT_DAY()` works with a number in SQL, but it doesn't work with a number in PL/SQL:

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 2) FROM dual;
```

returns:

> 3/23/2015 3:16:11 PM

However,

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Monday: ' || NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 2) );
END;
/
```

raises an error:

> [Error] Script lines: 1-4 --------------------------  ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week

So in your stored procedure, use a string for the second parameter of `NEXT_DAY()`:

```
IF trunc(:NEW.Inizio_ptz_aula) < trunc(next_day(sysdate, 'MONDAY'))
```

Comment: "not working" is not helpful ... does it return the same error or a different one?

Comment: Could it be your NLS settings? I see your table names and column names are Italian. Try `lunedi` in place of 'Monday'.

Comment: for the beard of merlin, it works. I haven't changed my default settings tough so it's kind of wierd. Probably in the installation something happend. Well thank you very much sir

Answer (score 2):

Replacing 1 for MONDAY in nextday statement does the trick

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Controllo_prenotazione
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Prenotazione
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
EX_ONE EXCEPTION;
EX_TWO EXCEPTION;
BEGIN 

 IF trunc(:NEW.Inizio_ptz_aula) < trunc(next_day(sysdate,'MONDAY'))
 THEN RAISE EX_ONE;
 END IF;

  IF to_number(to_char(sysdate,'d'),'9') > 5
 THEN RAISE EX_TWO;
  END IF;
  EXCEPTION
 WHEN EX_ONE THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-200011,'Non e possibile   prenotare nella settimana corrente');
  WHEN EX_TWO THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-200012,'Non e possibile prenotare nel weekend');
  END;
  /
```

It is quite strange behaviour because this works as a select statement, but not in trigger

```
  select next_day(sysdate,1) from dual;
```

Comment: It does oddly enough. However, days of the week begin with Sunday as 1. Therefore the equivalent SQL would be `SELECT NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 2) FROM dual;`

Comment: @HepC, the day of the week, as a number, depends on your NLS settings.

Comment: maybe i should check my nls settings to know what to put in there then ? How can i do it ?

Comment: did you try  'LUNEDI' instead of 'MONDAY' ?